# Command components inside a p:carousel wrapped by a p:dataGrid using LazyDataModel<T> do not invoke action(Listener)s, when the bean is request scoped

Tags: jsf, primefaces, carousel, actionlistener, lazydatamodel

Example :

```
<p:dataGrid var="dRow" value="#{testBean}" lazy="true" rows="1" columns="1">
    <p:carousel var="cRow" value="#{dRow.subCategories}" headerText="#{dRow.catName}" itemStyle="width : 300px">
        <!--Show images but that part is excluded for brevity.-->
        <p:commandLink process="@this" value="#{cRow.subCatName}" actionListener="#{testBean.action(cRow)}"/>
    </p:carousel>
</p:dataGrid>
```

The managed bean :

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class TestBean extends LazyDataModel<Category> {

    @Inject
    private DataStore dataStore;
    private List<Category> categories;

    public TestBean() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        categories = dataStore.getCategories();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
        List<Category> list = dataStore.getCategories();
        setRowCount(list.size());
        return list;
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void action(SubCategory subCategory) {
        System.out.println("action() invoked : " + subCategory.getSubCatName());
    }
}
```

The bean is decorated with `@RequestScoped`. `DataStore` is an application scoped bean where the `List<Category>` is created and stored.

The given command link does not trigger the action listener method (`action()`) in the managed bean unless either the bean is decorated with `@ViewScoped` (or wider) or the lazy data model is removed.

Thus, changing,

```
<p:dataGrid var="dRow" value="#{testBean}" .../>
```

to

```
<p:dataGrid var="dRow" value="#{testBean.categories}" .../>
```

will work i.e. the `<p:commandLink>` will invoke the action listener given (The lazy data model is excluded here. The given `<p:dataGrid>` is directly populated by a `List<Category>` from the backing bean).

Another alternative is to use a wider scoped bean like a view scoped bean as stated earlier.

Is it possible to use a request scoped bean along with a lazy data model in the given situation so that command components inside those components can work? I have many such view scoped beans just because of `<p:commandLink>`s inside a `<p:carousel>` wrapped by a `<p:dataGrid>` which could otherwise have simply been declared request scoped.

---

In case the application scoped bean where the list is maintained and the domain model classes are needed.

The application scoped bean :

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataStore {

    private List<Category> categories;

    public DataStore() {}

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        categories = new ArrayList<>();

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCatId(1L);
        category.setCatName("Animals");
        categories.add(category);

        List<SubCategory> subCategories = category.getSubCategories();

        SubCategory subCategory = new SubCategory();
        subCategory.setSubCatId(1L);
        subCategory.setSubCatName("Aquatic");
        subCategory.setCategory(category);
        subCategories.add(subCategory);

        subCategory = new SubCategory();
        subCategory.setSubCatId(2L);
        subCategory.setSubCatName("Aerial");
        subCategory.setCategory(category);
        subCategories.add(subCategory);

        subCategory = new SubCategory();
        subCategory.setSubCatId(3L);
        subCategory.setSubCatName("Mammals");
        subCategory.setCategory(category);
        subCategories.add(subCategory);
    }

    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
}
```

The domain class `Category` :

```
public class Category implements Serializable {

    private Long catId;
    private String catName;
    private List<SubCategory> subCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Category() {}

    public Long getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }

    public void setCatId(Long catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }

    public String getCatName() {
        return catName;
    }

    public void setCatName(String catName) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }

    public List<SubCategory> getSubCategories() {
        return subCategories;
    }

    public void setSubCategories(List<SubCategory> subCategories) {
        this.subCategories = subCategories;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(getCatId());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (!(that instanceof Category)) {
            return false;
        }

        return this == that || Objects.equals(getCatId(), ((Category) that).getCatId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s[catId=%d]", getClass().getCanonicalName(), getCatId());
    }
}
```

The domain class `SubCategory` :

```
public class SubCategory implements Serializable {

    private Long subCatId;
    private String subCatName;
    private Category category;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public SubCategory() {}

    public Long getSubCatId() {
        return subCatId;
    }

    public void setSubCatId(Long subCatId) {
        this.subCatId = subCatId;
    }

    public String getSubCatName() {
        return subCatName;
    }

    public void setSubCatName(String subCatName) {
        this.subCatName = subCatName;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 47 * hash + Objects.hashCode(getSubCatId());
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object that) {
        if (!(that instanceof SubCategory)) {
            return false;
        }

        return this == that || Objects.equals(getSubCatId(), ((SubCategory) that).getSubCatId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s[subCatId=%d]", getClass().getCanonicalName(), getSubCatId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that  if you remove the carousel and put the button directly inside the datagrid, it works?

Comment: Is this not just 4. in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked?

Comment: Only if it is at least a view scoped bean (needless to mention because it also happens just fine in the depicted scenario). Not enough sure about the 4th point in the linked answer. Hence, the question. It happens correctly in a request scoped bean, if the lazy data model is removed and the said list is initialized in a method decorated with `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: If the list that is constructed in the postconstruct is identical (not just content but object wise) that explains why it works then. Or am I missing something?